# Variant of Counting sort /Sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

there is a problem which gives me a random number as a pivot, and i have to sort my array w.r.t to this pivot (closest come first then farthest)
for e.g.

```
array =[2,7,4,6,4,4,5,3,6,9,1,1,9] and 

    pivot=5 

    expected output: [5,4,4,6,6,3,7,2,1,1,9,9]
```

is this a variation of counting sort by any chance? if not ! can anyone give me a clue towards solving this problem?
I am encountering a roadblock in thinking on how to handle the counts and the array indices 
Therefore, so far i have been able to do this

```
class HelloEclipse{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N=sc.nextInt();
    int pivot=sc.nextInt();
    int[] mainArray=new int[N];
    int[] differenceArray=new int[N];
    int[] differnceCountArray=new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        mainArray[i]=sc.nextInt();
        differenceArray[i]=pivot-mainArray[i];
        if(differenceArray[i]>0){
        differnceCountArray[differenceArray[i]]++;}
        else{
            differnceCountArray[-differenceArray[i]]++;
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed will be helpful!

Comment: Why not use Arrays.sort() to sort after populating the difference array

Comment: What is the possible range of the array elements? Are they all integers and within 'reasonable' distance from the pivot?

Comment: A problem you will face with a plain sort is that a negative *distance* is not correctly sorted (in the problem's sense). It should be sorted first by `abs()` and then by the value. Probably you have to write your own `Comparator`.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yes, i have populated the mainArray as an int[] array, so all elements are integers from 0 to Integer.MAX_VALUE , I am not sure what reasonable distance means and i do not think that is of any relevance as least distance elements are first then larger distances

Comment: @brijs I am  not sure how sorting the difference array helps my cause, since i need to sort  the elements as absolute distances from the pivot so i can put elements like 4 and 6 one after the other since they are at  distance 1 from pivot=5

Comment: @HardikVats Counting/bucket sort make sense only when the number of integers are large and the range of values that they can take is small. If that is so then you can get away with linear time, otherwise a comparison based sorting algorithm is usually more efficient.

Comment: @HardikVats use Math.abs() to store absolute difference of indexes from pivot index in difference array

Comment: @AbhishekBansal duly noted,and will keep in  mind..However, for the current problem, I am taking the number of elements as well as a pivot in `Scanner` and i would like to keep it that way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a suitable Integer-Comparator and use Arays.sort:

```
public class PivotComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    private int pivot;

    public PivotComparator(int pivot) {
        super();
        this.pivot = pivot;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Math.abs(a - pivot) - Math.abs(b - pivot);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] toSort = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        Comparator<Integer> comp = new PivotComparator(5);

        Arrays.sort(toSort, comp);
        for (Integer i : toSort) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

to get all the fours in front of the sixes you could do(instead of sorting twice)

```
public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
    int diff = Math.abs(a - pivot) - Math.abs(b - pivot);
    if (diff != 0) {
        return diff;
    }
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: just to make sure I have understood correctly, u have made a child class of `Comparator` and overridden its compare method  and that over riding  puts in order of absolute difference from pivot  the elements and you use that comparator as an argument to the  Arrays.sort() method , Please let me know  if I haven't fully understood/misinterpreted anything!

Comment: It's an implementation of an Interface, not exactly a child class(I connect child class more to inheritance) , but yes to the rest.

Comment: This is a completely exhaustive solution with the edit , it takes care of the fact that before only absolute distances were a measure to list the elements (and the order in which they were put in the original array)and not necessarily returning all instances of one number before the next number with the same distances were  returned ,extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation

```
    int[] array = { 2, 7, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6, 9, 1, 1, 9 };
    int pivot = 5;
    int[] sorted = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().sorted().sorted((i1, i2) -> Math.abs(i1 - pivot) - Math.abs(i2 - pivot)).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
```

output

```
[5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 1, 1, 9, 9]
```

Comment: not aware about streams and the associated methods  ,hence its a little difficult to understand the approach ,would you care to elaborate though the approach and briefly how a stream helps in the approach ?or is that something i need to study  myself? ,though a little hint would be extremely helpful! Your implementation is perfect and checked it out for other cases as well!!